# Read TXT file in PHP with control characters

Tags: php, mysql

How to read the following TXT file in PHP:
[example.txt](http://www.physics.ttk.pte.hu/example.txt)

The # characters are the control (separation) character, for example 2846 is the printer ID, and the following datas are the parameters of printer with ID 2846. It must be read that:

ID: 2846

+sn --> .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.1.4.0 = STRING: "censored"

+m --> .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Aficio MP 171"

+s --> .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.1.1.2.0 = STRING: "1.03"

... etc. The +sn, +m, etc are the parameters of printer. After the @ character can be read the agent's datas. The -- character is the closing control character. Then these parameters should be saved in variables so that it can be loaded into a mysql table.

I tried programming the scripts, but I don't know how to read the file.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','demo');
if(!$conn) die(mysqli_error());

$open = fopen('example.txt','r');
while (!feof($open)) {
    $getTextLine = fgets($open);

    /* reading txt file, separating values of control parameters of printer
        the code...
    */

    list($ID,$sn,$m,$s,...etc) = $explodeLine;
    $qry = "insert into agent_name (ID,sn,m,s,...etc) values('".$ID."','".$sn."','".$m."','".$s.",...etc')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
}

fclose($open);

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This routine will read lines from the file and build it up into an array of the lines, then when it reaches a line which just contains a `#` it will then process the data.

The data is split up so that first you get the ID and then it picks alternate lines of the flag followed by the setting and creates an associative array of the settings.

```
$open = fopen('example.txt','r');
fgets($open); // Ignore first line
$entry = [];
while (!feof($open)) {
    $getTextLine = trim(fgets($open));

    if ( $getTextLine == '#' )  {
        // Take ID as first line
        $settings = ['ID' => array_shift($entry)];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($entry); $i+=2 )    {
            $settings[ltrim($entry[$i],"+")] = $entry[$i+1]??'';
        }

        print_r($settings);
        //     list($ID,$sn,$m,$s,...etc) = $explodeLine;
        //     $qry = "insert into agent_name (ID,sn,m,s,...etc) values('".$ID."','".$sn."','".$m."','".$s.",...etc')";
        //     mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
        $entry = [];
    }
    else    {
        $entry[] = $getTextLine;
    }
}
```

at the moment it prints out the data, but you should be able to insert it into the database.  Although I would recommend looking into prepared statements to ensure no quotes or other oddities cause problems with the SQL.

A sample output is for the first entry...

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 2846
    [sn] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.1.4.0 = STRING: "censored"
    [m] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "Aficio MP 171"
    [s] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.1.1.2.0 = STRING: "1.03"
    [ff] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.1 = INTEGER: 254623
    [fffc] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.23 = INTEGER: 746801
    [ffny] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.6 = INTEGER: 230398
    [ffm] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.19 = INTEGER: 19932
    [scff] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.29 = INTEGER: 4476
    [scsz] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.19.5.1.9.28 = INTEGER: 3549
    [fb] => .1.3.6.1.4.1.367.3.2.1.2.24.1.1.5.1 = INTEGER: -3
)
```

Updated code...

```
$open = fopen('example.txt','r');
fgets($open); // Ignore first line
$entry = [];
$all_settings = [];
while (!feof($open)) {
    $getTextLine = trim(fgets($open));

    if ( $getTextLine == '#' )  {
        // Take ID as first line
        $settings = ['ID' => array_shift($entry)];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($entry); $i+=2 )    {
            $settings[ltrim($entry[$i],"+")] = $entry[$i+1]??'';
        }

        $all_settings [] = $settings;
        $entry = [];
    }
    else    {
        $entry[] = $getTextLine;
    }
}

print_r($all_settings);
```

Comment: I tried this code, and the output is only first set of data.

Comment: With the donwloaded file you gave in the question, the last one I get is `[ID] => 11285`

Comment: One thing you will find is that not all entries have every setting, so you may need to code for some not being in the array.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. [printscreen](http://www.physics.ttk.pte.hu/example.jpg)

Comment: Sorry to ask - can you check the file your reading is the same as the one linked to in the question.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. I will check the correct file. This is the new printscreen: [link](http://www.physics.ttk.pte.hu/example2.jpg).

Comment: I've updated the line `$settings[ltrim($entry[$i],"+")] = $entry[$i+1]??'';` can you try that.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the many questions, how I get the keys of a given array? For example I would like to get the ID of second array that is: $settings['ID'][2] or the ID of third array: $settings['ID'][3], etc... (sorry for the complicated question)

Comment: I've added a new code example which stores up all of the settings.  With this you can do `$all_settings[0]['ID']` or `foreach ($all_settings as $setting) { echo $setting['ID'].PHP_EOL; }`

Comment: Oh, a last question. How I get the datas of agent after the @ character?